# Java's >> versus >>> Operator?

Tags: java, operators, bit-manipulation

I'm without my Java reference book and I'm having a tough time finding an answer with Google.

What is the difference between the ">>" and ">>>" operators in Java?

```
int value = 0x0100;

int result = (value >> 8);
System.out.println("(value >> 8) = " + result);  // Prints: "(value >> 8) = 1"

result = (value >>> 8);
System.out.println("(value >>> 8) = " + result); // Prints: "(value >>> 8) = 1"
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Difference between >>> and >>](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2811319/1529630), [Difference between >>> and >> operators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1972356/1529630)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`>>>` is [logical shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift), `>>` is [arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift).

- `0xDEADBEEF >>> 8` ⇒ `0x00DEADBE` *(logical shift, the one you want)*
- `0xDEADBEEF  >> 8` ⇒ `0xFFDEADBE` *(arithmetic shift)*

Answer (score 23):

Signed integers use the high-order bit to denote sign.

So `>>` preserves the sign, while `>>>` doesn't. This is why `>>` is referred to as the *arithmetic* shift and `>>>` is the *logical* shift.

This way, you can do (assuming 32-bit integers) the following:

- `-10 >> 1` yields -5 (`0xFFFFFFF6 >> 1` yields 0xFFFFFFFB - notice the high-order bit stays the same.)
- `-10 >>> 1` yields 2147483643 (`0xFFFFFFF6 >>> 1` yields 0x7FFFFFFB - notice all of the bits were shifted, so the high-order bit is now zero.  The number is no longer negative according to twos-complement arithemetic.)

For positive integers, `>>` and `>>>` act the same, since the high-order bit is already zero.

It also explains why there is no need for a `<<<` operator. Since the sign would be trashed by sliding the bits to the left, it would map to no reasonable arithmetic operation.

Comment: @BillK Although the answer is good, but haven't you seen that when you are going to comment, SO asks you not to write things like **+1** or **thanks** ?

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh I wouldn't normally but I thought it was useful to point out that this should be voted up above the accepted answer (seems to have worked).  Would it have been better if I just said "Most useful answer"?  Also, are you absolutely certain that guideline existed in '09?

Answer (score 9):

From [**Java Notes: Bitwise Operators**](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/bitops.html):

**n >> p** *(right shift)*
Shifts the bits of n right p  positions. If n is a 2's complement signed number, the sign bit is shifted into the high-order positions.

*Example:* 5 >> 2 = 1

**n >>> p** *(right shift)*
Shifts the bits of n right p positions. Zeros are shifted into the high-order positions.

*Example:* -4 >>> 28 = 15

Answer (score 7):

For positive numbers, there is no difference. Negative (two's complement) numbers will be filled with zeros for >>> and ones for >>.

1010 0110 >>>2 = 0010 1001

1010 0110 >> 2 = 1110 1001

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer has been posted more than once, but not from an authoritative source.

This is from the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) [§15.19 Shift Operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.19):

> The *shift operators* include left shift `<<`, signed right shift `>>`, and unsigned right shift `>>>`; they are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right). The left-hand operand of a shift operator is the value to be shifted; the right-hand operand specifies the shift distance.
>
> ...
>
> The value of `n>>s` is `n` right-shifted `s` bit positions with sign-extension. The resulting value is ⌊*n*/2<sup>*s*</sup>⌋. For nonnegative values of `n`, this is equivalent to truncating integer division, as computed by the integer division operator `/`, by two to the power `s`.
>
> The value of `n>>>s` is `n` right-shifted `s` bit positions with zero-extension. If `n` is positive, then the result is the same as that of `n>>s`; if `n` is negative, the result is equal to that of the expression `(n>>s)+(2<<~s)` if the type of the left-hand operand is `int`, and to the result of the expression `(n>>s)+(2L<<~s)` if the type of the left-hand operand is `long`. The added term `(2<<~s)` or `(2L<<~s)` cancels out the propagated sign bit. (Note that, because of the implicit masking of the right-hand operand of a shift operator, `~s` as a shift distance is equivalent to `31-s` when shifting an `int` value and to `63-s` when shifting a `long` value.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reply. It answers a different question I had: How to effectively perform an arithmetic shift on a CPU that has only logical shifts. "(n>>s)+(2<<~s)" seems a good answer to that :-)

Answer (score 2):

The >> is an arithmetic shift, which preserves the sign bit in any 'vacant' bits.  The other is a logical shift which fills the vacant spots with zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

The arithmetic shift >> is division by two for signed integers, while the logical shift >>> is division by two for unsigned numbers (if you interpret the bit pattern in a signed Java int as an unsigned integer).

Answer (score 0):

some [info](http://www.sap-img.com/java/java-bitwise-shift-operators.htm)

> the >> operator preserves the leftmost bits. The leftmost bits are filled with the previous content. This is to do with sign extension. In this case there is a 1 at the left and it is preserved. If you do not want to keep the 1 to the left, use the >>> operator which shifts 0's into the leftmost bits

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with signed value math. The `>>>` pills in zeros for the hight order bits, the `>>` preservers the sign bit and pulls it in.