# What is >> in java?

Tags: java, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double Greater Than Sign (>>) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050989/double-greater-than-sign-in-java)

What does the following achieve ?

```
int num = (10-2) >> 1;
```

Found this very helpful -

[What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting)

Comment: Do we need so many duplicate answers? Please people, stop posting identical answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its bitwise right shift in java.
it shifts all binary digits,1 place towards right and pastes a zero at the leftmost end.
(10-2)=8 which is 1000 in binary,
now right shifting each digit and pasting 0 at the leftmost position, it gives 0100 which equals 4.

Comment: This answer is not correct: >> does preserve the leftmost digit (which is the sign indicator) whereas >>> does insert a `0` at the leftmost position. You may prove this by `0xFFFFFFFF >> 1` and `0xFFFFFFFF >>> 1`.

Comment: @Harmlezz But `0xFFFFFFFF >> 1 ` gives -1 which is also `0xFFFFFFFF`. This seems weird!

Comment: @foobar `0xFFFFFFFF` means all bits are set to `1`. The `>>` operator shifts all bits one position to the right and preserves the left-most bit, which is `1`. Hence the value `0xFFFFFFFF` won't change. Its not weird but consequent :-)

Answer (score 10):

Shift right. It moves all the bits of the number right by the number specified

10-2 = 8 = 1000 in binary

8 >> 1 = 1000 >> 1 = 100 in binary = 4

Comment: And what happens when you shift `-1` to the right?  Might as well have a complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

`>>` is just an [operator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) to perform bitwise right shift

Answer (score 0):

Right shift the indicated number of bits.

Comment: OP could probably use a little bit of explanation. Chances are if OP doesn't know what the right shift operator is then OP doesn't know what the operation does either.

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

First result on google for ">> operator java"

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation here on [Bitwise shift right](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)