# How to add decimal point before x digits in Java

Tags: java, formatter

Lets suppose I have a value 12345678 and a number say x=2, and I want the final output as 123456.78 and if the value of x is 4, the final output would be 1234.5678.

Please tell how would I can achieve this?

Comment: divide it by `100.0` for X 2, and by `1000.0` for X 4

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050989/double-greater-than-sign-in-java

Comment: @Habib: I don't think that brining floating-point into it is necessarily a great idea (assuming the `12345678` in the question is an `int`.)

Comment: @NPE: I think it's fine to bring floating-point into it. I just wouldn't bring floating *binary* point.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't know about you, but I've not actually seen a single hardware implementation of floating *decimal* point. :) It's a bit like saying that we can't compute an integer power of two by using the shift operator because this assumes a binary computer and not, say, a ternary one (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setun) :)

Comment: @NPE: Who said anything about a hardware implementation? `BigDecimal` is the Java representation of a floating decimal point number, just like `System.Decimal` is the .NET representation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that you're dealing with shifting a *decimal* point, I'd probably use `BigDecimal`:

```
long integral = 12345678L;
int x = 4; // Or 2, or whatever
BigDecimal unscaled = new BigDecimal(integral);
BigDecimal scaled = unscaled.scaleByPowerOfTen(-x);
System.out.println(scaled); // 1234.5678
```

Answer (score 7):

```
BigInteger d = new BigInteger("12345");
BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal(d, 3);//12.345
BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal(d, 2);//123.45
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out :

```
String data = "12345678";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(data);
    int x = 4;
    builder.insert(builder.length() - x, ".");

    System.out.println(builder);
```

Comment: I think you have to parse the data again and again, if `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the value by 10 raise to the power x.