# What is the ">>" and ">>>" operator in java?

Tags: java, operators

Hi I was wondering if anyone could help me with something I can find literally nothing online about.
I was looking through some code that had the following statement:

int mainInt = 10>>> 5;

Does anyone know what this >> operator is?

For example 10 >> 1 equals 5
            20 >>> equals  3

Thanks

Comment: You can't shift 20 to get a 3, because 20's binary representation is `10100` and `3` is `11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>>` is the [arithmetic right-shift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift).

`>>>` is the [logical right-shift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Logical_shift).

The first one preserves the sign of the operand. The second inserts zeros at the most significant bit positions, and is usually applied on unsigned numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered: [Double Greater Than Sign (>>) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050989/double-greater-than-sign-in-java)

> The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left,
>   and the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the
>   right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the
>   number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand. The unsigned
>   right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position,
>   while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

You can read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).