# Difference between >>> and >> operators

Tags: java, bit-shift

If the shifted number is positive >>> and >> work the same.

If the shifted number is negative >>> fills the most significant bits with 1s whereas >> operation shifts filling the MSBs with 0.

Is my understanding correct?

If the negative numbers are stored with the MSB set to 1 and not the 2s complement way that Java uses the the operators would behave entirely differently, correct?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Difference between >>> and >>](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2811319/1529630), [Java's >> versus >>> Operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1034640/1529630)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way negative numbers are represented is called 2's complement. To demonstrate how this works, take -12 as an example. 12, in binary, is 00001100 (assume integers are 8 bits though in reality they are much bigger). Take the 2's complement by simply inverting every bit, and you get 11110011. Then, simply add 1 to get 11110100. Notice that if you apply the same steps again, you get positive 12 back.

The >>> shifts in zero no matter what, so 12 >>> 1 should give you 00000110, which is 6, and (-12) >>> 1 should give you 01111010, which is 122. If you actually try this in Java, you'll get a much bigger number since Java ints are actually much bigger than 8 bits.

The >> shifts in a bit identical to the highest bit, so that positive numbers stay positive and negative numbers stay negative. 12 >> 1 is 00000110 (still 6) and (-12) >> 1 would be 11111010 which is negative 6.

Answer (score 2):

[Definition of the `>>>` operator in the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#40638):

> The value of `n>>>s` is n right-shifted s bit positions with zero-extension. If n is positive, then the result is the same as that of `n>>s`; if n is negative, the result is equal to that of the expression `(n>>s)+(2<<~s)` if the type of the left-hand operand is `int`, and to the result of the expression `(n>>s)+(2L<<~s`) if the type of the left-hand operand is `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Just the opposite, the >>> fills with zeros while >> fills with ones if the h.o bit is 1.

Comment: Can you explain why `7>>>32=7`. I heard of circular shifts, but I thought that only applied to `>>`. Wouldn't `7>>>32` after 32 shifts just equal to zero?

Comment: @IanLimarta: If the left hand side is an int, the shift amount is reduced mod 32. In your case, that means the shift amount is 0, which is effectively a no-op. See [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)