# Difference between >> and >>> operators in Java

Tags: java, bit-shift

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between >>> and >> operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972356/difference-between-and-operators)

I'm getting confusion about >> and >>> operator.So please guide me with some example about >> and >>> operator.
Thanks

Comment: AFAIK: >> keeps the sign bit, while >>> does not

Comment: See actually i wanna know about logic how this(operator) generates output .

Comment: Take a look into the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: You should search, this question has been posted several times in SO and Java documentation is pretty clear, http://googleitforme.eu/?q=java+operators