# Meaning of ">>>" in Java

Tags: java, operators

So i got this code that im trying to understand, but i don't know the meaning of this operator:

```
paramInt >>>= 7;
```

If you guys could tell me that would be awesome! Thanks

Comment: [Java Tutorial: Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: And in particular: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: Try Google or the official manual: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972356/difference-between-and-operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>>>=` is similar to `+=` but with a unsigned right shift (`>>>`) operation.

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("1000", 2);
//shift 3 times to the right : "1000" becomes "0001" = "1"
foo>>>=3;
System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString(foo));
```

output :

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

It shifts a zero into the leftmost position of 7 and assigns the value to paramInt. The new paramInt value will be 3.